# Boy on airplane suddenly wakes up tiny and under a hedge

Tags: story-identification, young-adult, childrens-novel, urban-fantasy

I read these YA (or older children's) books between 2005 and 2007, and I think they had been published fairly recently at that time.

- The protagonist is a young teen boy who is flying on an airplane with his family, possibly arguing with his sibling (don't recall if brother or sister).
- Next thing he knows he's waking up in what seems like a jungle with plants that just seem wrong. With a little exploration he realizes he's the size of a bug and has awakened underneath the hedge that lines his yard.
- It is a harrowing journey to avoid the birds just to travel across the yard to the house and look into a window.
- It seems like maybe he wonders that his family isn't worried about where he is and then he realizes there's a doppelganger in his place who is far more accommodating and thus gets along better with his family. (I am not at all certain about this line item.)
- I think he eventually gets the attention of his sibling (or best friend) using sidewalk chalk and s/he helps him. S/he might take him along to school one day.
- I'm certain there was at least one and possibly two more books in the series.
- At some point in the series, possibly the second book, he finds a group of other teens who have been shrunk and they are living in a cave.
- They have a fireplace, possibly made from a tin can.
- I think one girl spends a lot of time braiding rope for them to use to climb.
- There may or may not be a shoe or boot that he (or the group) uses to hide behind.

Almost all of the vague memories above could be off by a little or a lot. Sorry. Any help appreciated. :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[The Dark Ground](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/1049594.The_Dark_Ground) by Gillian Cross

> Robert wakes up naked and alone in a thick jungle. The last thing he
>   remembers is being in a plane with his family, but there is no sign of
>   a crash or survivors. Then he discovers the shocking truth--he is in
>   the park near his house, but his familiar world has been transformed
>   into an alien landscape. When he finds others in the same position, he
>   enlists their help in getting back home. But the journey is more
>   perilous than Robert could ever imagine.

Comment: This is it! Thank you!